# How to get multiple selectedvalues from listbox in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, email, listbox, selectedvalue

I am doıng a email sender as a part of my program. In the form , I have listbox that is loaded with this code:

```
connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        connection.Open();
        string sql = "SELECT Email,(CONVERT(varchar(2),FlatNo)+'- '+Name+' '+Surname) AS FullName FROM People " +
                     "ORDER BY FlatNo ";

        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(dt);
        listBox1.DisplayMember="FullName";
        listBox1.ValueMember = "Email";
        listBox1.DataSource = dt;
        connection.Close();
```

I have sendEmail(string toPerson) function. When I click the send button, I call email function as sendEmail(listbox1.selectedValue). It works if I choose one item but when I select multpile items , it only sends 1th one. How can I loop into selectedValues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `SelectedItems` property the get multiple selection values:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selecteditems(v=vs.110).aspx

Or you can used the `SelectedIndices` property the get the index of the selected items instead.

Comment: SelectedIndices works but I still cant reach selectedValue. To use selectedIndices,  I need one more sql connection function and send this indices value and return email as string. In this case selectedValues is meaningless.

Comment: I did that way I said above , thanks for selectedindices idea

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var listBoxItem in listBox1.Items )
         {
           list<string> x=new list<string>();
           if(listBox1.SelectedItem==true)
           {
            x.add(listBox1.SelectedItem[i];
           } 

        }
```

now you have the List x which contains all selected items from listbox